# Cannot run chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Today I found some kind of bug launching chrome.
If name is `chrome.exe` it won't start.
I tried to run it from CMD. It says: 
The system cannot find the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe.`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e3x1.png]
But after renaming for example to `chrom.exe` it works.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXscg.jpg]

Comment: With anything wacky like this I would look at virus/malware followed by corrupt disk

Comment: Is this a business/work or personal computer?

Answer (score 0):

1- Your EXE file name in the screen shot is **Chrom.exe** and the file you are trying to launch is **Chrome.exe**

2-The first screenshot contains **Chrome.exe** with a blank icon maybe it is altered by a virus, but renaming the file ?? maybe you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your AV is interfering with it. Try and disable Windows Defender (and/or whatever other AV you've got), ensure the firewall is off and try again. As Rob says, it may be virus/malware so if the mentioned fails, scan your PC for virus etc.

Comment: This isn't really an answer you are just guessing

Answer (score -1):

I would immediately suspect a virus infection. Do a malware scan with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) (my favorite) or similar software and see what you can find.